# replace string after pattern with filename

Tags: bash, sed, text-processing

I have multiple .gbf files on which I need to replace everything after every instance of the word DEFINITION to the end of the line with its respective filename (considering two spaces in between).

filename example: GCF_000219725.1_ASM882v1___Lalala_holae_9a5c.gbf

section of interest in files:

```
DEFINITION  random_chacacters_including_spaces
```

wanted output:

```
DEFINITION  GCF_000219725.1_ASM882v1___Lalala_holae_9a5c.gbf
```

Was thinking something like:

```
for f in *.gbf; do sed 's/DEFINITION  .*$/DEFINITION  "$f"/g'; done
```

which didn't work

Thanks

Comment: Because single quotes does not expand variables for starters.

Comment: How can I fix that @Jetchisel ?

Comment: can please put complete example of the filename and the output you want.

Comment: Yes. Edited above.

Comment: What happen to the `DEFINITION` in the original filename?

Comment: It stays the same.

Comment: You need to feed the filename to `sed` as an argument. Please try: `for f in *.gbf; do sed -i "s/DEFINITION  .*/DEFINITION  $f/g" "$f"; done`.

Comment: @Manuel, changing `"$f"` to `'"$f"'` in your attempt should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt contains two errors:

- it uses `$f` in a single quoted expression (yes, the two `"`s are parte of the single quoted expression too);
- the `sed` command is not provided with the filename, which is `$f` as an argument;
- besides, there's no need for the `g` flag in the `s` command.

So what you want to do is actually the following:

```
for f in *.gbf
do
  sed 's/DEFINITION  .*$/DEFINITION  '"$f"'/' "$f" > "$f.new"
done
```

where the `sed` script is a concatenation of three strings which are, in order, single-quoted, double-quoted, single-quoted. This approach keeps preventing expansion in the single quoted parts, while allowing it in double quoted parts. In the specific example you presented, there's no difference, but in general it is advisable to single quote strings (and `sed` commands are strings), unless you need to double quote them (cf. [Learning the bash Shell, 3rd Edition, top of page 147](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do)). In the latter case, the `sed` command would be:

```
  sed "s/DEFINITION  .*$/DEFINITION  $f/" "$f" > "$f.new"
```

Furthermore, you need to put the output somewhere, e.g. in a new file named `$f.new` (or you can use `sed`'s `-i` option, which is not POSIX, if I correctly remember).